# I Want to Place a custom icon along the progressBar of MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

[image]

This is the following design I'm Using MUI linerProgressBar now i want add a custom UI Icon along the progress goes on is there any example like this?

I tried to find any example in MUI but haven't got any if there is please do let me know

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [docs on customizing](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-nested-component-styles) the slider styling.

Then you can make use of a CSS psudo element:

```css
.parent-selector .MuiSlider-thumb:before {
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  background-image: url('path-to-svg-folder/download.svg');
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}
```